# How to call particular ID within another ID in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, identifier

This is the content of page2.html

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="pageone">  
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="site_wrap wrap">
            <div class="img_slides_wrap slides_wrap wrap">  

            <div>    <img id="slide1" class="img_slide slide active" src="img/slide0.jpg" alt="" title=""/> </div>
             <div>   <img id="slide2" class="img_slide slide" src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="" title=""/> </div>
             <div>   <img id="slide3" class="img_slide slide" src="img/slide2.jpg" alt="" title=""/> </div>
             <div>    <img id="slide4" class="img_slide slide" src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="" title=""/> </div>
             <div>   <img id="slide5" class="img_slide slide" src="img/slide4.jpg" alt="" title=""/> </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <a href="#pagetwo">SHARE</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

now i need to get "slide3" on Onclick of third image from page1.html heres the code for it

```
<li> <a href='page1.html#pageone#slide3' ><img src="img/thumb/a.jpg" alt="Image a" width="30" height="48"/></a></li>
```

The issue is i'm not able to get slide3 when clicked on third image from page2.html instead able to get 1st image... where i'm i going wrong please help me.

Answer (score 3):

An ID must be **unique** within a document.

You cannot have duplicate IDs.

URL fragment identifier syntax does not support "X in Y" syntax as "X" must be unique so "in Y" will be redundant.

All you need, if your HTML is [valid](http://validator.w3.org), is `href="page1.html#slide3"`.

Comment: ID with another ID with different names will not work? then how to proceed next when i want to get values? @Quentin

Comment: @DD. — As I said, you just use the id (having made sure that your HTML is valid so it doesn't have duplicate ids).

Comment: href="page1.html#slide3" i had tried with this piece of code before itself, but it shows slide1 page... @Quentin

Comment: It [works for me](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/19739867/page1.html#slide3)

Comment: dude u have placed the code directly not under any id or class, since i'm using swipe function for the images at page2.html so cant remove the classes and id from it. @Quentin

Comment: Edited the test case to put another div with a different id around each slide div, it still works. I have no idea what you mean by "swipe function for the images".

Answer (score 0):

Call Each id from number ranging from 1 to 10.Like #slide1 to #slide10.And you can easily call it like `href="page1.html#slide3"`.

Comment: i tried but its not working... since Id id="pageone" is already declared at the top.. @Dhanith Suryavansi